# How can I use Keycloak in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, keycloak

I'm trying to authenticate in Keycloak in Next.js using `@react-keycloak/nextjs` but once I pass the login it keeps sending me back to the Keycloak server and returning to the main page until it gives me an error because my token key is expired.
This is my `_app.js`:

```
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/react-hooks'
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline'
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import { Persistors, SSRKeycloakProvider } from '@react-keycloak/nextjs'
import Layout from 'components/layout/Layout'
import { useApollo } from 'lib/apolloClient'
import KeycloakLoading from 'components/KeycloakLoading'
import {
  keycloakCfg,
  keycloakProviderInitConfig,
  onKeycloakLogout,
  onKeycloakTokens,
} from 'lib/keycloak'
import Head from 'next/head'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import React from 'react'
import theme from 'styles/theme'
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'
import 'react-leaflet-markercluster/dist/styles.min.css'
import 'styles/styles.css'
import 'styles/animations.css'
import '../styles/globals.css'

// export function reportWebVitals(metric) {
//   // These metrics can be sent to any analytics service
//   console.log(metric)
// }

export default function MyApp(props) {
  const { Component, pageProps, cookies } = props

  const apolloClient = useApollo(pageProps.initialApolloState)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Remove the server-side injected CSS.
    const jssStyles = document.querySelector('#jss-server-side')
    if (jssStyles) {
      jssStyles.parentElement.removeChild(jssStyles)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Head>
        <title>My page</title>
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width"
        />
      </Head>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <SSRKeycloakProvider
          keycloakConfig={keycloakCfg}
          persistor={Persistors.Cookies(cookies)}
          initConfig={keycloakProviderInitConfig}
          onTokens={onKeycloakTokens}
          onAuthLogout={onKeycloakLogout}
          LoadingComponent={
            <React.Fragment>
              <KeycloakLoading />
            </React.Fragment>
          }
        >
          <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
            <Layout>
              <Component {...pageProps} />
            </Layout>
          </ApolloProvider>
        </SSRKeycloakProvider>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

MyApp.propTypes = {
  Component: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired,
  pageProps: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  cookies: PropTypes.any,
}
```

And this is my Keycloak configuration

```
export const keycloakCfg = {
  realm: APP_CONSTANTS.KEYCLOAK_REALM,
  url: `${APP_CONSTANTS.KEYCLOAK_HOST}/auth`,
  clientId: APP_CONSTANTS.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
}
export const keycloakProviderInitConfig = {
  onLoad: 'login-required',
}
```

If anyone could point out what is wrong or alternatively tell me another way to use Keycloak in next.

Comment: hello did it work? can i see the repository because i am also working on nextjs resources with keycloak

Answer (score 8, accepted):

React-keycloak/nextjs is deprecated in favor of react-keycloak/ssr. I followed the examples here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-keycloak/ssr and was able to fully authenticate without issue.

I'm not sure what is causing your looping issues but it doesn't look like you are using the required cookie parser or passing them into the props via getInitialProps so that may be a good place to start.

Comment: It already works. Do you know how to pass scopes in this lib?

Comment: It's okay, not perfect though. Protecting Next API routes is not offered out of the box, while integrating the keycloak-connect in the next api's middle-ware is another story.

Answer (score 7):

An alternative would be:
[Next-Auth](https://next-auth.js.org/) has implemented a [keycloak provider](https://next-auth.js.org/providers/keycloak) which would make your life much easier protecting both Frontend and Backend. Just specify keycloak options/configs in _app.js and you all set.

```
import {signOut, getSession, useSession } from 'next-auth/react';

export default function Home() {
  let session = useSession();
  console.log(session);
  return (
    <div >
      <button onClick={() => {
        console.log(session);
        signOut();
        console.log(session);
      }}> Sign Out </button>
      <h1>H1 test</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {

  const backendSession = await getSession(ctx)

  console.log(backendSession);
  return {
    props: {

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am facing numerous issue in Keycloak with NextAuth, Token Rotation, Token Expiry when offline you name it, numberous issues are open in NextAuth. It is a nightmare for me personally.

Comment: @Mahesh have you adopted something else? I'm looking at options and am a bit unwilling to write it from scratch :)

Comment: next auth is still a nightmare for me,  i had to work on three projects with next auth,  all three had bugs like token expiry and stuffs.  ended up converting one to a vite project and am using react-keycloak/web